# ssh closes connection immediately after successful login for a specific user

Tags: linux, ssh

This starts driving me nuts! 
I have the case here where a specific user when trying to login to a Linux server (running openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)) using a password or a private key is immediately logged out again.
The login seems successful (at least according to the ssh log - see below) but immediately after that the connection is closed and the intended command is not executed.

The below output captured using ssh's -vvv option:

```
ssh -vvv -i <path_to_private_key> <user>@<FQDN> touch /tmp/mms_was_here

...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:W4i/<removed> <path_to_private_key>
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:W4i/<removed-same-as-above>
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:W4i/<removed-same-as-above>
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <FQDN> ([10.10.8.88]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to <FQDN> closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2564, received 2328 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 400692.9, received 363811.6
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Note: I replaced a few appearances of the server's name and some key hashes for privacy but they were correct.

What makes things even more absurd to me is that a different user can log in without problems (with both, password or key authentication)! I painstakingly compared settings, the content of the .ssh directory and what not. They are the same (modulo the different keys of course).

Both user have a valid home directory set as well as `/bin/bash` as default shell. Their public keys have been added to the respective  `~/.ssh/authorized keys`-files, the server's `hosts.deny` and `host.allow` files are empty (or rather contain only comments). `sshd_config` has neither an AllowUser/Group nor a DenyUser/Group section.
The password (for password authentication) is set and unlocked. But that user can not login!

After the login attempts of both "service sshd status" reports:

```
...
30:3d:c6:43:ee:3d:05:32:90:49:65:71:1a [MD5]
May 14 15:43:17 ksta-zhquest-int3 sshd[26223]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <user> by (uid=0)
```

So - even that looks good. sshd has admitted the user. But then one user's command is executed while the other's session is immediately closed again and the command is NOT executed! And that happens for both, password as well as key authentication! Why is that user locked out? Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue, it turned out that:

1. The subnet that I had put the particular Debian VM on, was not listed in Active Directory sites and services. Adding that subnet in AD Sites and Services fixed the issue for me.

It took me ages to find the answer and this question kept coming up in my searches, so I'm posting the answer here in case anyone is in the same boat in future.

Some other other scenarios with similar or identical symptoms:

1. `PasswordAuthentication=No` was set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I was attempting authentication using a password.
2. The user had no homefolder. `/var/log/auth.log` showed the authentication succeeding but then the client side disconnected straight afterwards. I had forgotten to configure `/etc/pam.d/common-session` with `session optional pam_mkhomedir.so`
3. (Ansible) I had a conflicting variable set in the inventory file causing it to try and use ssh key authentication instead of password authentication. This was only visible with `-vvv` showing ansible using `ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user is not added to some nologin configuration, it also could have set its default shell to /bin/false or something alike

Comment: No, the default shell - as I wrote - is set to /bin/bash. Are there other ways to specify a nologin config for a specific user?

Comment: yes, there are other ways, I am not really familiar with SUSE, but maybe something in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow.  Are you able to login with other user and then su -  to that user that deny access?

Comment: The password is NOT locked and also not expired and there is no '!' before the user's hash in /etc/shadow (I know that method to disable a user's login and that wouldn't explain why the login doesn't work using an SSH key, either). 
And - yes - I can sudo to that user without any problem. I just can't directly login...

Answer (score 0):

I had a look-alike problem once upgrading an openSUSE computer from a 15.3 release to Tumbleweed. It turned out that there was an old `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file left over in the file system which contained in the line for "Subsystem sftp" a binary file `/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server` that does not exist. The problem was solved by removing (sic) that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file such that the file at the slightly different location `/usr/etc/sshd_config` took over, which contained an valid `Subsystem sftp` binary file in the `/usr/libexec` directory, then restarting the sshd .

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to connect again(may be it refreshed the connection).

In VS Code, go to

**settings>user>extensions>Remote-SSH>Remote.SSH: Remote Platform>**

1.click edit pen icon for host you have problem with.

2.Just select the **platform** again as **linux/windows**.

3.Save the changes.

I tried to reconnect with ssh again and it had the successful connection.